# error in npm install

Tags: npm, dependencies, npm-install

I always get this error when I run

```
 npm install
```

any one have any idea how to solve it

```
 npm ERR! Darwin 13.0.0
 npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
 npm ERR! node v4.1.2
 npm ERR! npm  v3.3.5

 npm ERR! Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined
 npm ERR!
```

It seems to be in the path 
but how to solve it ?

Comment: Some people are reporting that this was fixed by upgrading to the latest version of npm. https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9766 I would try that.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jack Zelig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136887/jack-zelig) suggested in the comment updating npm worked for me. My npm was at `v3.3.6`

**To update npm run:**

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

After update I am at `v4.0.5`  and the error is no longer shown when I run npm install.